# Uniformly distributed points on spherical surface

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, differential-geometry, probability-distributions

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be uniformly distributed on the $(n-1)$-dimensional spherical surface $S^{n-1}(n^\frac{1}{2})$ of radius $n^\frac{1}{2}$. I'm trying to show that as $n\to\infty$, $x_1$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable.

As noted in the introduction of [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkl8u3qa5x00jkv/2959482.pdf?dl=0) article, 
for $-n^\frac{1}{2}<a<b<n^\frac{1}{2},$
the uniform measure of the spherical zone $a\leq x_1<b$ is

$$
\frac{\int_a^b (n-x^2)^{n/2-1}dx}{\int_{-n^\frac{1}{2}}^{n^\frac{1}{2}}(n-x^2)^{n/2-1}dx}.
$$

I know this is probably very straightforward, but I'm stuck right now---could someone please explain the above formula for the uniform measure?

EDIT

This result can alternatively be obtained as follows: We introduce auxiliary iid standard normal random variables $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ and
$$
z_j=\frac{y_j}{(y_1^2+\cdots+y_n^2)^{1/2}n^{-1/2}}.
$$
Then we show that $z=(z_1,\cdots,z_n)\in S^{n-1}(n^\frac{1}{2})$, that $x_1$ and $z_1$ have the same distribution, and that $z_1$ converges in distribution to $y_1.$

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "spherical zone $a \leq x_1 \leq b$" ?

Comment: It should be $\{x\in S^{n-1}(n^\frac{1}{2}) : a\leq x_1<b\},$ but this doesn't seem to make sense in the case $n=2$ because the formula gives a uniform distribution...

Comment: Hint: Use that $(1-x^2/n)^{n/2-1}\to e^{-x^2/2}$ (and the case $n=2$, while offtopic, makes perfect sense, thank you).

Comment: (Of course it makes sense as Did said. It seemed to not make sense because I was embarassaingly confused.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region, $R_{x_1, a,b}:=\left\{ x\in S^{n-1}(n^\frac{1}{2}) : a\leq x_1<b \right\}$, defines a collection of "$n-2$"-dimensional surfaces.

1. For $n=3$, the sphere is a $2$-dimensional surface and the region is a collection of $1$-dimensional circles that lie in the sphere, each uniquely identified by $x_1$.
2. For $n=2$, the sphere is a $1$-dimensional sphere (i.e. circle) and the region is a collection of pairs of $0$-dimensional points, each uniquely identified by $x_1$.

The stated measure, $$\frac{\int_a^b (\sqrt{n-x^2})^{n-2}\mathrm dx}{\int_{-n^\frac{1}{2}}^{n^\frac{1}{2}}(\sqrt{n-x^2})^{n-2}\mathrm dx}\,,$$ gives the uniform distribution over $S^{n-1}(\sqrt{n})$ when applied to the aforementioned collection of "$n-2$"-dimensional surfaces. It is simply a ratio of "$n-1$"-volumes (note that the volume of $S^{n-1}(r)$ is proportional to $r^{n-1}$). So, in the case of $n=2$, it is a ratio of lengths.

And, in the $2$-dimensional case, it describes a uniform distribution of pairs of points (i.e. a pair for each $x_1 \in [a,b)$) *on the circle*, and **not** the distribution of the projection of these points. That is, for the uniform measure $P$ over $S^1$,

$$
P\left(x\in R_{x_1, a,b}\right) = \frac{\int_a^b \mathrm dx}{\int_{-n^\frac{1}{2}}^{n^\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm dx} = \frac{b-a}{2\sqrt{n}}\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense, and it should have made sense from the start!

Comment: @Aubrey, You are welcome